# How do I open a template document in OfficeWebApp with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, office-web-apps

I am using the following to open a template document from one location which will be saved to a another location:

```
<a href="javascript:'" onclick="CoreInvoke(&#39;createNewDocumentWithRedirect2&#39;,event,&#39;https:\u002f\u002fMYO365SITE.sharepoint.com\u002fsites\u002fTesting\u002fShared Documents\u002ftemplate.docx&#39;, &#39;https:\u002f\u002fMYO365SITE.sharepoint.com\u002fsites\u002fTesting\u002fShared Documents&#39;, &#39;SharePoint.OpenDocuments&#39;, false, &#39;https://MYO365SITE.sharepoint.com/Testing/_layouts/CreateNewDocument.aspx?id=https://MYO365SITE.sharepoint.com/Testing/Shared%20Documents/template.docx&#39;, true, 1); return false;" href="#">CreateNewDocument</a>
```

This works fine on my PC where the document opens in word (desktop app) and when I press save it picks up my (destination document library) location.

The issue is my tablet (IPad). The link direct me to a form page which asks for the Document Name. After pressing OK, I receive a failed to create file error.

Any suggestions for altering the above script to force SharePoint to use Office Web App instead of opening the doc in the desktop app? I think this might overcome my issue.

Comment: Why do you have two href attributes on your link?

Comment: no reason. good point. removed the`href="'javascript:'`. The issue remains, however I have added some more details above.